# Reading MS Office BuiltInDocumentProperties in Delphi

Tags: delphi, office365, ms-office

I am trying to read specific properties in office documents, but I am having difficulties with certain properties, specifically date properties and document data properties such as no of pages, no of lines etc. I am using Delphi 10.4 and testing with MS Office 365.

**Date Problems**
I get an unspecified OLEException when I try and read the values of "Last Save Time" and "Last Print Date".
As for "Creation Date" I can read without error, but it always returns the value as today's date (which is incorrect).

**Data Problems**
"No of Pages" always returns 1 regardless. Other values such as "No of Lines", "No of Characters" return 0.

I couldn't find much on the web re reading the date and data properties of Office documents. But what I could find suggested that something like the following code should work.

```
var
  MSApp, Props, item: Variant;
  i: integer; 
begin
  MSApp := CreateOLEObject('Word.Application');
  MSApp.Documents.OpenNoRepairDialog(filename, false, true, false, password, password,
        False, password, password, emptyParam, emptyParam, false, true);

  MSApp.ActiveDocument.Repaginate;

  Props := MSAPP.ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties;

  for i := 1 to Props.Count do
    begin
      item := props.item[i];
      try 
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Item Name='+item.Name+sLineBreak+'Value='+VarToStr(item.value));  
      except
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Item Name='+item.Name);
      end;
   end;
 end;
```

Comment: Assign result of `OpenNoRepairDialog` to a variable and use it instead of `MSApp.ActiveDocument`.

Comment: I will reply here under the question, because it is not related to the answer. I have tested the code (with 2013, currently no acccess to 365) and with the change mentioned above there was no problem reading any of the properties in question.

Comment: @BrakNicku OK. I tried again your way an this time it worked! I also tried again my original way and that is also now working even with the same documents! Very frustrating, but thanks for testing it.

Comment: I am surprised it works using `ActiveDocument` (if you still test it using `Visible=false`). In any case you should not rely on this property and use return value of  `OpenNoRepairDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want do easier and use only docx, just unzip the Word document, you will get xml files (core.xml) with all the value of the document (created, modified, ..)

Comment: I suppose I could save the document in docx format and then extract the props xml files. But by doing so I would presumably change some info such as Last saved data. I could use IPropertyStorage to read the data for older files, but I would prefer to use one function if possible. I don't see why BuiltInDocumentProperties does not work in Delphi for the various properties I have identified.

Comment: @MarkWilliams _I don't see why BuiltInDocumentProperties does not work in Delphi_ did you try what I suggested above? Your current code does not check the document you open, but a blank new one.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. I am opening the file specified by filename. That becomes the active document. It reads the properties of that document correctly save for the errors and anomalies mentioned above. However, for completeness, I have assigned the document to a variant and it has exactly the same problems.

Comment: @MarkWilliams _That becomes the active document._ This isn't true at least for my version of Office (2013), maybe it was changed in later version, but it would be strange, because  you set `Visible` input parametert to false. Every symptom of missing/incorect fields suggested that you are in fact inspecting a blank and unsaved document.

Comment: @BrakNicku It's true for mine. Anyway, it isn't the issue because I have done it your way and I still get these issues. Have you tried it yourself to see if you can read the various problematic fields?